Trying to find movie or trailer about shooter movie-like videogame
After watching Season 3, episode 2 of Black Mirror, I remember a recent trailer about a movie where the actors are in a shooter videogame. They thought it was just a game, but they actually start dying.
Scarce details I can remember:

They use a vest or helmet to connect to the game
clothing was like gray jumpsuits
they were on an high building

The movie is not:
Stay Alive.
Subterano.
Gamer (2009)

I think you might be looking for "The Call Up". The trailer shows everything your looking for but they are in a high building instead of on it.



I hope that helps.
